# Which high risk ports need to be blocked in the print server?

Tags: port, network-share, print-server

Can you please help in finding the high risk ports that are to be blocked for the printer server.

Server is on a Hyper V platform.
OS : Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Comment: You're going the wrong way about it. You shouldn't be blacklisting "known dangerous" ports; you should be whitelisting the few ports that you need. In other words, block everything that you do not specifically need.

Comment: Pricisely. Block all, open only what is needed. And not just for a print server. Use that approach for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the built in Security Configuration Wizard (scw.exe) on the server. Select/Deselect the appropriate items (roles, features, options, services, etc.), and let the SCW "harden" the server for you. Note that the actions taken by the SCW (based on your selections) are completely reversible.